# cakephp v2 layout not loading

Tags: cakephp, layout, view, cakephp-2.1

Hi I want to add a new layout to my cakephp, but somehow the system keeps looking in the view folder from the controller instead of the /app/View/Layouts folder.

```
Error: The view for TestsController::desktop() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: /app/View/Tests/desktop.ctp
```

the desktop.ctp file is in /app/View/Layouts. The same place as the default.ctp

The code in the controller is:

```
public function desktop() {

    $this->layout = 'desktop';
}
```

What is wrong here? I don't understand why cakephp keeps looking in the view/controller-name folder... I need this fixed because I want to use this layout for other controllers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the message carefully, you'll see cake is telling you it cannot find your **view**, not your layout.

So, create an empty `/app/View/Tests/desktop.ctp` and see what happens. I'm hoping magic.. :)

Comment: oh snap! well, maybe for this test I didn't need the view... cake still does!